# Can I spray paint threads on a scissor jack?

Tags: paint, jack

I have a very old looking scissor jack for my vehicle. I want it to look at least half decent so I'm spraypainting it black.

Does it matter at all if I paint the threads? I don't really care if the paint on the threads get messed up, I'm just more-so concerned about whether this would damage the jack in any way.

I'm painting it with rustoleum glossy black, could it slip at all either on the actual part that contacts the lifting point or the threading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be an issue with painting the threads or having paint on there. If you are really worried about it, though, just liberally grease the threads prior to painting. This will keep the paint off the threads themselves, plus the added bonus of preventive maintenance (no rust on the threads, so ready to use when needed). If you coat them *very* liberally, then paint the jack, let the paint dry, then wipe off any excess from the threads, you should be golden.

Comment: I think this is the better answer, as spray painting the thread may cause extra friction, which makes it harder to operate the jack.

Answer (score 3):

Painting it will not cause the threads to slip under load. There's way too much [mechanical advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_advantage) put in when lifting the jack/load for it to slip back like that.